# Jquery не видит подключаемые плагины (fancybox, colorbox и т.п.)

Tags: jquery

Есть сайт (небольшая панель управления, показать не могу), есть вот такой **script.js** :

```js
// DOM ready event
$(function(){
 // run scripts in .page block
 $('.page:first').run();
});


// Run scripts in selected jQuery block
$.fn.run = function() {

 var $root = this,
  $window = $(window);

 $root.find('.js-box').each(function(){
  $(this).click(function(){
   $.colorbox({
    data: { ajax : 'y' },
    href: $(this).attr('href'),
    width: '950px',
    onComplete: function(){
     $('#cboxLoadedContent').run();
    }
   });
   return false;
  });

 });

};
```

По клику на ссылку js-box (которая отсылает по ajax команду с параметрами обработчику), всплывает окно с ответом, точнее должно всплывать. Но выдаёт ошибку $.colorbox is not a function http://joxi.ru/n2Y813XIBZQGm6 . Попробовал отдельно от ajax просто вызвать colorbox:

```js
$(function(){
 // run scripts in .page block
 $('.page:first').run();
 $(".js-box").colorbox();
});
```

Ошибку получил тут же, ту же самую http://joxi.ru/ZrJV5lkSlM5Xrj . Проверил порядок вызова скриптов и вообще подключаются они или нет, всё на месте, порядок вызова правильный http://joxi.ru/EA4NOP4fyOkYmb , файлы проверил, всё подключается. Почему jqiery их не видит?

P.S. версия **Jquery 1.11.3** , версия **colorbox 1.5.5**

Answer (score 1):

Ну вроде очевидно, что не подгружается `colorbox` или не выполняется.

1. Посмотрите на месте-ли файл jquery.colorbox.js;
2. Можно дописать в конец какую ниудь глобальную переменную или alert('colorbox loaded'); чтобы убедиться что он действительно загружается (jquery, как я понимаю, уже явно к этому моменту загружен);
3. Еще можно в colorbox убедиться в наличии `$.fn.colorbox` после присваивания (искать присваивание `$.fn[colorbox]` и вставить после `console.log($.fn.colorbox);`)

Comment: вы знаете тут какая-то ересь, вместе с остальными скриптами подключался jquery.tools.js (код не мой я его только правлю и что тут к чему до конца не знаю), так вот когда я вывел в конслоль `console.log($)` вывелась `function(a,b)` в консоли, я туда кликнул и консоль показала jquery 1.2.7 . Удалил jquery.tools.js ,  и `console.log($)` стал показывать jQuery именно той версии которую я подключил 1.11.3 и всё заработало. Я в шоке ...

Comment: Ну теперь смотрите что там внутри кроме древнего jQuery. Может теперь еще какой-то функционал отключен. Правка чужого кода - отдельный навык в программировании :) Иногда это бывает чертовски интересно

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```js
j=jQuery.noConflict();
j(function(){
 // run scripts in .page block
 j('.page:first').run();
 j(".js-box").colorbox();
});
```

Вместо всех $ пишите j